# OpenLayers 4 set map target with jQuery

Tags: openlayers, jquery

I have a div element

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

And I have a map

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [map_layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: Map_1_view
});
```

I try this to set target

```
 $("#map").data("my_map",  map);
```

but it didn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with

```
 map.setTarget($("#map")[0]);
```